# VueJS GET request with Bearer token

Tags: vue.js, axios, kentico-kontent

I am experimenting with Kentico Delivery Preview API using VueJS, which allows you to get unpublished content by submitting a bearer token for authorisation (https://developer.kenticocloud.com/reference#authentication). However, no matter what I do I get a 401 in response. PROJECT_ID, ITEM_NAME and TOKEN are all correct, taken from the project, so it's not a typo issue. I admit I don't have much experience with auth, but any help would be appreciated:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
          .request({
            url: '/items/ITEM_NAME',
            method: 'get',
            baseURL: 'https://preview-deliver.kenticocloud.com/PROJECT_ID',
            headers: {
                'Authorisation': 'Bearer TOKEN'
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
          })
      }

})
```

Comment: First change to Authorization with z

Comment: Oh goddamit. That's what I get for being English haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As pointed out by Walter in the comments, I spelt Authorization with an S rather than a Z.. because I'm English. Whoops.

Comment: I cannot right now; I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer(!). I will mark it accepted in 2 hours when the ban is lifted. Please vote it up in the meantime!

Answer (score -1):

Use create to config axios headers before your request

```
const TOKEN = 'Token';
const BASEURL = 'https://preview-deliver.kenticocloud.com/PROJECT_ID';
const ENDPOINT = '/items/ITEM_NAME';

axios.create({
        baseURL: BASEURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+TOKEN
        }
    })
    .get(ENDPOINT)
    .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
    });
```